# Access LLDB / set breakpoints when running simple swift file from command line

Tags: swift, command-line, lldb

I have a simple Swift script that I'd like to step into using LLDB but having a hard time making sense of the documentation. If I run the following inside the REPL:

```
:target create ./myswiftfile.swift
```

I get back

```
error: './test.swift' doesn't contain any 'host' platform architectures: x86_64h, x86_64, i386
```

Is it possible to either set the arch from inside the REPL or otherwise invoke `myswiftfile` in a way that gets me into the debugger? I realize I can debug inside Xcode using the Command Line Tool template but it's a shame given how lightweight a simple Swift script can be. Basically looking for `pdb` for Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lldb does not currently support compiling swift files for you and then loading them into the debugger or the REPL.  It wouldn't be all that hard to do.  The best thing to do is to file an enhancement request with bugreporter.apple.com.